# Why are "::before" and "::after" showing up when inspecting HTML5?

Tags: html

I keep seeing the pseudo selectors `::before` and `::after` in HTML files lately. I have only seen these used in CSS in the past.

Does anyone know why a developer would use these in their HTML. I have one example screenshot to show what I am talking about. The same is on other sites as well:

[image: html inspect pseudo elements]

Comment: This is the browser's tools showing you where they are so that you can inspect them; the developer did not physically include them in the markup.

Comment: you're seeing this if you're using inspect elements of a page in a browser. not try viewing the source. it's not there.

Comment: please put the real code in content ,don't put the picture ,it not is use ,thanks

Comment: I appreciate the quick feed back. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try right-clicking and selecting "View Page Source"

It won't be there in the source.

The "::before" and "::after" text in your screenshot was only there as a result of Inspect Element visually displaying the CSS selectors to make it visible how "::before" and "::after" were used in CSS.

For example, here are two images. The first one is inspect element. The other one is the unchanged source.

[Click here for the picture of Inspect Element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnAe0.png)

[Click here for the picture of the unchanged source code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrCL.png)

Hopefully that helped.

This is my first answer! :-)

Best Regards, 
-Gauched

Answer (score 0):

Before and After selectors can be used in CSS, If the styles for before and after is specified then it will appear in html or else it wont appear in HTML.